# How can I find the area of the surface $(u,v) \mapsto (u,v,uv)$ in the domain $A = \{(u, v) \in \mathbb R^2\colon\ u^2+v^2<3\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Consider the set
$A = \{(u, v) \in \mathbb R^2\colon\ u^2+v^2<3\}$.
What is the area of the surface $\sigma: A \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by
$\sigma(u,v)=(u,v,uv)$?

$(A)14/
3\quad\
(B) 14π/3
\quad\
(C) 9π\quad\
(D) 9$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Actually, I am reading this for the purpose of interest and I am only a little bit acquainted with it. I do not understand whether it is a vector or scalar field. and the path. Moreover, different websites are showing different formula of surface area. Please help me if you know this.

Comment: It’s not too hard once you know that the area will be given by $\bigint_A ||\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial v}||\ du\,dv$. But the motivation or how you’d evaluate this integral needs a bit of multivariable calculus.

Comment: Please solve it. I am not acquainted with it. Atleast tell me the correct answer so that I can know what I have calculated is right or wrong. Please

Comment: I do not know what will be the limits of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write the domain as $D$. It is known from multivariable calculus that the area $A$ which you want to calculate is given by

$$A = \int_D \| \sigma_u \times \sigma_v \| \ \mathrm d u \mathrm d v.$$

We have $\sigma_u = (1, 0, v)$ and $\sigma_v = (0, 1, u)$, hence $\| \sigma_u \times \sigma_v \| = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2 + 1}$. Now we introduce polar coordinates, then it follows that

$$A = \int_D \sqrt{u^2 + v^2 + 1} \ \mathrm d u \mathrm d v = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{r^2 + 1} \ r \mathrm d r \mathrm d \varphi = \frac{14\pi}{3}.$$